# Cache webpack modules between entry points

Tags: webpack

I need to generate a per-customer file for our library, but the library itself it the same, and the only difference is a single customer configuration file that is being added to the main library file.

The way we do it today is:

```
{
  entry: {
    customer1: ["customer1-config.js", "main.js"],
    customer2: ["customer2-config.js", "main.js"],
  }
}
```

The problem with this, is that the `main.js` file is being re-built for each and every customer.

Is there a way to only build it once and merge it together for each customer?

Update: The output should be that each entry point will containt the entire `main.js` file & the custom customer config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do two builds:

- The first one builds the code without the configuration as a module exporting your library. This allows for easy testing of configuration, and only happens *once* for all your clients.
- The first just requires your main output module (the product of your first build) from the `dist` folder, requires it and then adds the configuration on top.

I've successfully done this to solve the problem. It's not the most elegant solution but it works in practice. It adds only a little bit of complexity and the advantage is that other clients can customize your library.

Comment: can you bring example `webpack` config ?